# Initial capitalization of foreign surnames when starting a sentence

Tags: sentence, capitalization, surnames

In the book, "The Crystal Shard," by R.A. Salvatore, a character is surnamed "de Bernezan." Which of the following complete sentences uses the correct English-language capitalization:

- de Bernezan entered the room.
- De Bernezan entered the room.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Vries) on "de Vries" capitalized "De Vries" as a standalone, but writes "Marc de Vries" when using the full name.

Edits in response to comments:

- The book starts sentences as "de Bernezan," which seems incorrect. Hence my question.
- The Wikipedia page is neither authoritative nor clear. It seems to refers to "De Vries" as the correct capitalization of the surname, except when actually used as a surname. Since I am not Dutch, I do not know how their names work, especially when used in an English-language context. Again, hence my question.

Comment: And why is that not your answer?

Comment: The rule is: capitalize words when they start a sentence. The only exception I know of is Dutch names that start with 't.

Comment: In fact the book itself is likely to answer the question.

Comment: From my edits above in response to comments: The book's capitalization is "de Bernezan," which seems incorrect. Since the author (presumably) knows more about language than I do, I thought I'd seek some kind of definitive reference here to resolve the question.

Comment: One of our regular contributors here is @oerkelens, a native speaker of Dutch (if I am not mistaken). Perhaps he will explain how this issue is handled.

Comment: @RegDwight The rule for foreign surnames. Other usages have mandatory lowercase, demanded by scientific bodies, businesses etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fortunately, *The Chicago Manual of Style* (16th edition) deals with this question on page 388:

> **8.5 Names with particles.** Many names include particles such as *de, d', de la, von, van,* and *ten*. Practice with regard to capitalization and spacing the particles varies widely, and
> confirmation should be sought in a biographical dictionary or other
> authoritative source. When the surname is used alone, the particle is
> usually retained, capitalized or lowercased and spaced as in the full
> name (**though always capitalized when beginning a
> sentence**). [emphasis added]

So, following *Chicago*, the correct sentence is, "De Bernezan entered the room."

The variation in capitalization you found on the De Vries Wikipedia page is explained by the Chicago rule for Dutch names used in an English context (page 390):

> **8.10 Dutch names.** In English usage, the particles *van, van den, ter,* and the like are lowercased when full names are given but
> usually capitalized when only the last name is used.
>
> Johannes van Keulen; Van Keulen
>
> Pieter van den Keere; Van den Keere
>
> Vincent van Gogh; Van Gogh
>
> Gerard ter Borch; Ter Borch

Answer (score 2):

The case of a reference list of an academic paper will be covered in my answer.
(Sorry, not directly relevant to the OP, but [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/246157) is redirected here.)

APA Style says, according to [*APA Style Blog: How to Capitalize Author Names in APA Style*](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/02/how-to-capitalize-author-names-in-apa-style.html), in a reference list, lowercase is retained:

> de Haan, A. D., Deković, M., & Prinzie, P. (2012). Longitudinal impact of parental and adolescent personality on parenting. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 102, 189–199. doi:10.1037/a0025254

APA Style agrees with the Chicago Manual for the sentence beginning. *After a colon* capitalization is necessary, too. Thus:

> - De Haan, Deković, and Prinzie (2012) studied the impact of parental and adolescent personality on parenting.
> - Recently, researchers have explored the impact of personality on parenting: De Haan, Deković, and Prinzie (2012) used longitudinal analyses to untangle the effects.