# Should I capitalize a person's last name if their name starts with a lower case letter but it's the first word in the sentence?

Tags: names, citation

I'm trying to cite someone in a paper I'm writing whose name is "[First-name] de Soya". In my field it's common to cite papers using the "et al." style ("In their seminal paper, de Soya et al. […] present…"), however, "de Soya" is opening the sentence.

In that case, should I write "de Soya et al. […]" or "De Soya et al. […]"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's normal for the first letter of sentences to be capitalized in languages where this could occur (e.g. "Von Neumann isst" not "von Neumann isst" in German).

Comment: To be complete, see [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/463567/9614) to the ["duplicate" target question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/185852). In short, lowercase is retained in a reference list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely cannot reword the sentence to put the name somewhere else, then, yes, you need to capitalize *de Soya*.

Sentences **always** need capital first letters. However, an extremely special case is a sentence beginning with a word such as *iTunes*. The lowercase *i* is allowed because the very next letter is capitalized. This creates a slight gray area in terms of where the capital letter has to be in the first word, but it's a rule nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

yes

yes, it should be capitalized regardless of the origin of the last name.  if possible then you should try to reword the sentence so you do not have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a pen name (such as bell hooks for example), it seems acceptable to use it as such at the beginning of a sentence. ("bell hooks wrote her reflections on liberatory pedagogies...", S. Mitchem, Journal of Women and Religion, 1999). It's not the last name however, but the entire name.