# Should the surname 'de Menezes' be capitalised on beginning a sentence?

Tags: capitalization

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keir_Starmer) (Keir Starmer's entry, the UK Labour Party Leader) has the following :

> Within the first few months of his tenure, Starmer upheld the decision not to prosecute the officers who had killed Jean-Charles de Menezes in a High Court appeal lodged by the family.

> de Menezes was shot dead by police in 2005 after he was mistaken for a suicide bomber.

I would have expected 'de Menezes' to be capitalised to 'De Menezes' at the beginning of a sentence.

Am I wrong ?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185852/initial-capitalization-of-foreign-surnames-when-starting-a-sentence +++ also read [this article](https://www.librarything.com/topic/153671#:~:text=The%20official%20rule%20was%20that,case%20it%20should%20be%20capitalized)

Comment: Thank you. That answers it.